# How to enable solr.SimplePatternTokenizerFactory in Solr schemaless mode?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I want to create filter based on data provided in one of the Tag fields, for example:

tagField: master:industry/financial-services/asset-management/alternative-investments
tagField: master:industry/financial-services/asset-management/investments
tagField: master:industry/financial-services/asset-management/investment_test

When querying, I need to arrange in such a way that they act as a filter when displayed on the page with simple json response from java server side:

```
dropdown 1:master_industry 
              dropdown 2:financial-services (based on dropdown 1)
                        dropdown 3: asset-management (based on dropdown 2)
                            dropdown 4: alternative-investments  (based on dropdown 3)
                                         investments
                                         investment_test
```

I am aware of the following support in Solr, for example:

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[A-Z][A-Za-z]*" group="0"/>
</analyzer>
```

However what I want is to enable this pattern in schemaless mode (I can't edit schema.xml).

How can I do that ?

Comment: It looks like you meant to add an example in your question but I don't see it. (?)

Comment: @HectorCorrea I just fixed it, it was not correctly formatted ;)